# Whether to use quote marks for a certain word in a phrase I need to reference

Tags: punctuation

I'm looking to quote a funny saying for a poster/t-shirt.

A fan once said of a famous sporting player (who was very limited in his approach to the game, always kicking):

> *He had six different signals and they all meant kick*

Should the word *kick* be in quotation marks or anything else? The original source quote did not use them, but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is to rhyme with six, both may be treated equally. Using a quote mark is fine if you think it is quote-worthy.

Comment: Thanks, I think I prefer without. So you think that will work ok and is correct?

Comment: I don't think it is relevant whether or not the phrase is 'quote-worthy'. Strictly speaking, a word used as a definition should be marked out, either with quotation marks or in italics. It depends how 'correct' you want your poster to be. Perhaps the design could include putting 'kick' in a different typeface?

Comment: Thanks, Kate. I want it to be correct. The place I saw the quote did not have 'kick' in quote marks. But when I look at it, I wonder if it should have.

Comment: This is a stylistic choice.  You can leave "kick" in the normal case, you can put quotes around it, you can italicize it.  Your decision.

Comment: As a new creation, your T-shirt has freedom to exaggerate in calling extra attention to the word KICK. The general rule that all caps means you are shouting works in your favor here: your punchline is shouting as an athlete would.

Comment: You could argue whether the signal meant the word "kick" or the concept of kicking. I'm not sure how much this would help, but it's worth bearing in mind. I'd agree with previous posts that it doesn't matter much, if at all.